# Merge sort an array of strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am currently trying to implement a Merge Sort algorithm in Java based on the one found in Introduction to Algorithms: Third Edition.
The authors use a divide and conquer algorithm that also implements sentinel cards [(here is pseudo code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ8ru.png). These cards are supposed to have a value of infinity, but since I am using an array of strings, I assumed that the value would be `null`. Apparently that is not the case because when I try comparing L[i] and R[j] I get a Null Pointer Exception. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner textfile = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a filename: ");
    String fileName = textfile.nextLine();
    String[] words = readArray(fileName);
    mergeSort(words, 0, words.length - 1);
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }

}

public static String[] readArray(String file) {
    int ctr = 0;
    try {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            s1.nextLine();
        }
        String[] words = new String[ctr];
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++) {
            words[i] = s2.next();
        }
        return words;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
    return null;
}

public static void mergeSort(String[] A, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergeSort(A, p, q);
        mergeSort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, p, q, r);
    }
}

public static void merge(String[] A, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    String[] left = new String[n1 + 1];
    String[] right = new String[n2 + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        left[i] = A[p + i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        left[j] = A[q + j + 1];
    }
    left[n1] = null;
    right[n2] = null;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = p; k < r; k++) {
        if (left[i].compareTo(right[j]) <= 0) { \\Null Pointer Exception
            A[k] = left[i];
            i++;

        } else {
            A[k] = right[j];
            j++;

        }
    }
}
```

So what's the problem? Is it because I declared the two arrays as `null`? I tried things like "zzzz" and still get the same problem. Or am I completely missing something else?
Also, the pseudo code assumes that the array starts at index 1, which is why there are slight changes in my code. Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: "*I assumed that the value would be null. Apparently that is not the case because when I try comparing L[i] and R[j] I get a Null Pointer Exception.*"
Wait, are you being serious here? You declared the value as null and so it threw a null point exception, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: There's practically no Java string that's guaranteed to compare greater than any other string (and thus be suitable as a sentinel) so you could just test for i == n1 and j == n2.

Comment: @Riley Yeah, that does sound dumb. I only said that because I found [this](https://peace.csi.muohio.edu/trac/peace/browser/release-0.95/EAST/Java/src/com/mhhe/clrs2e/MergeSort.java). And when I use `compare()` it gives me an out of bounds exception on the same line. Sorry, I've just been at this all day.

Comment: Do you mean the `compare()` method on the last line of the class you linked? From what I see, it should work. When I looked at the `compareTo()` in the `String` class, it says it throws a `NullPointException` whenever a null value is passed in.

Comment: I also looked at the `compareTo()` in the `Comparable` class (which they are using in the code) and it throws a `NullPointException` as well.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @poniboy4: I can see you have been at it all day, when you write in the question: 'I tried things like "zzzz"' :)

Answer (score 0):

You're infinity-`String` must fulfill the following-property:

```
s.compareTo(infinityString) == -1
```

for **any** `s`, if you want to use [`String#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29). That being said `infinityString = null` doesn't yield the required properties, since it produces a `NullPointerException` if either in this code `a.compareTo(b)` either `a` or `b` is `infinityString`. There would be the **really** ugly workaround of simply using a sufficiently long `String` of arbitrary characters, such that there exists no equally long `String` in the input. But that's:

- a **really ugly and insecure** hack
- a waste of memory

Instead I'd recommend using one of these two approaches:

- use your own comparison-method instead of `String#compareTo`, that yields the property `compare(s , infinityString) = -1` for whatever you want to define `infinityString` to be.
- use an implementation of merge-sort without sentinel cards and simply eliminate the need for an infinity-element.